Date Time Format Returning Minutes Instead of Month
I have a button that consolidated text from a form into a specific text format. One of the inputs to the form is a date and time picker where you enter the date and time an organization received a report. I'm trying to format the date into the following format Date Time Month Year (dd hhmm mmm yy) as an example, February 1, 2024 at 1:00 PM should look like 01 1300 Feb 24.
The current code I'm using is
Text(IncidentGallery.Selected.'HQs Notified DTG',"dd hhmm mmm yy")```

It returns the following text: 08 1418 18 24 (reference data is May 8, 2024 at 2:18PM). Everything is correct other than where the mmm is shows minutes rather than the month. Thoughts on where I'm going worng?

Tried listing mmm multiple ways, no change in the result.


You are using lowercase "mmm" for the month instead of uppercase "MMM". Lowercase is for minutes, and uppercase for months.

I tried uppercase MMM and it returns as MMM in the text field.

I just checked the documentation at Text function, and lowercase "m" is used for the month and the minutes field, which really does not make sense. Have you tried one of the standard Date/Time format enumerations?

Yea, those don't work for the format I'm trying to apply. If I just have the date (dd mmm yy) it works fine, when I incorporate the time (hhmm) for a 24 hr format is where it's getting messed up.

Sorry, but as I said, it makes no sense to use the same letters for both minutes and months. There must be something missing from the documentation.

Playing around with the code I found if I do 'hhmm dd mmm yy' it works, but once I put the hhmm next the mmm it can't seem to separate the two sets of letters

An interesting problem. Glad you managed to fix it.
